# SQl having clause Min method invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL server Manager 2008
quick simple one,
Got this query:

```
SELECT sizecode as smaller
from safestore.dbo.SpaceMan_EvoPrices
WHERE SiteId = 'derp' AND Publish = 'Y' AND SizeCode = 'herp'
HAVING PhysicalSize < MIN(PhysicalSize)
```

is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Added a group by but not sure how to add it to the group by clause to be valid.
As you can tell I've never used Having until now.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

this query is the original query im attempting to shorten as its a head ache to look at:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (SELECT TOP 1 Sizecode 
FROM [safestore].[dbo].[SpaceMan_EvoPrices]
WHERE PhysicalSize < (SELECT TOP 1 PhysicalSize FROM [safestore].[dbo].   [SpaceMan_EvoPrices] WHERE SiteId = 'derp' AND Publish = 'Y' AND SizeCode =   'herp')
AND SiteId = 'derp'
ORDER BY PhysicalSize DESC) AS Smaller,
(SELECT TOP 1 Sizecode 
FROM [safestore].[dbo].[SpaceMan_EvoPrices]
WHERE PhysicalSize > (SELECT TOP 1 PhysicalSize FROM [safestore].[dbo].  [SpaceMan_EvoPrices] WHERE SiteId = 'derp' AND Publish = 'Y' AND SizeCode =   'herp')
AND SiteId = 'derp'
ORDER BY PhysicalSize) AS Larger
FROM [safestore].[dbo].[SpaceMan_EvoPrices]
```

Comment: Apart from the query aspect. How can something be smaller than its minimum ?

Comment: Do you intend to compare it with the minimum value for the whole ungrouped table?

Comment: ill update to explain, the query is part done so far so the logic is out at the moment

Comment: What is the logic in `HAVING PhysicalSize < MIN(PhysicalSize)`? You want to select rows with `PhysicalSize` less than the `MIN(PhysicalSize)` from same table? Will that return any rows? And you need to specify the `GROUP BY` clause or use Aggregate function to use [Having](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx).

Comment: like i said this was a start of the query, i was testing out having but got stuck on an error, thats all. if the having isnt needed then great, ive provided the rest of the code so people can see the big picture, and that this was a try out query to see if i needed having or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PhysicalSize, Publish, SizeCode
    FROM dbo.SpaceMan_EvoPrices
    WHERE SiteId = 'derp'
)
SELECT
      Smaller = (
        SELECT TOP 1 Sizecode
        FROM cte
        WHERE PhysicalSize < t.PhysicalSize
        ORDER BY PhysicalSize DESC
      )
    , Larger = (
        SELECT TOP 1 Sizecode
        FROM cte
        WHERE PhysicalSize > t.PhysicalSize
        ORDER BY PhysicalSize
      )
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 PhysicalSize
    FROM cte
    WHERE Publish = 'Y'
        AND SizeCode = 'herp'
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as your query is concerned.  it should be like this

```
SELECT sizecode as smaller,PhysicalSize 
from safestore.dbo.SpaceMan_EvoPrices
WHERE SiteId = '080P2DDK120820090001' AND Publish = 'Y' AND SizeCode = '50SA'
Group by PhysicalSize 
HAVING PhysicalSize < MIN(PhysicalSize)  --not sure y this line
```